# Unknown and Damaged Archive in django

Tags: python, django

This is code to download files but when file downloads and i open them :`the archive is unknown and damaged`. Can you please help me to solve this problem here code is:

```
def download(request):

    file_name =request.GET.get('file_name', '')
    the_file = "C:\\Users\\CV_Uploads\\uploadfiles\\uploadfiles\\uploaded_files\\1395901478_89_uploadfiles.rar"
    filename = os.path.basename(the_file)
    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(the_file)),
                           content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(the_file)[0])
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(the_file)    
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
    return response
```

Comment: You raw string for `the_file`

Comment: how to solve this @NishantN.

Comment: Have you tried `the_file = r"C:\Users\CV_Uploads\uploadfiles\uploadfiles\uploaded_files\1395901478_89_uploadfiles.rar"`

Comment: yes then it points at `r`

Comment: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Users\\CV_Uploads\\uploadfiles\\uploadfiles\\uploaded_files\\uploaded_files/1395913137_4_CV_Uploads.rar'

Comment: Remove double slash , and put only single

Comment: got my way :) thank's @NishantN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dealing with paths you should use `raw` string .

use

```
the_file = r"C:\Users\CV_Uploads\uploadfiles\uploadfiles\uploaded_files\1395901478_89_uploadfiles.rar"
```